# Reloading Guardfile on changes to files other than the Guardfile

Tags: ruby, guard

Currently, [`Guard::Setuper` reloads just the Guardfile when it changes](https://github.com/guard/guard/blob/master/lib/guard/setuper.rb#L188).

I'm loading some additional code into my guard file (via `require`), and I'd like to also reload when some of those required files change.

I guess I'm really just looking for a plugin, but that seems like I'd be trying resurrect [guard-ego](https://github.com/guard/guard-ego). Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: [`reevaluate_guardfile`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/j/joshbuddy-guard-0.10.0/Guard/Dsl.html#method-c-reevaluate_guardfile) is a DSL method that you should be able to use in a Guardfile matcher.

Comment: But what guard plugin would I declare that matcher under? (am I misunderstanding the DSL? Seems like everything needs to be within a guard :something block)

Comment: Hmm, I think I looked at an old version of the documentation, as I can't get it to work in a `watch` block.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try something like this in your Guardfile (using [guard-shell](https://github.com/hawx/guard-shell)):

```
guard :shell do
  watch(%r{path/to/your/required/files}) { Guard.evaluator.reevaluate_guardfile }
end
```

@Zach: Up-to-date documentation is at http://guardgem.org (usage) and http://rubydoc.info/github/guard/guard/master/frames (technical).