# Restart spring and guard after branch checkout (when Gemfile.lock is different)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restart, guard

When I have guard open and change branches, often the `Gemfile.lock` has another spring client. I then get this error:

```
There is a version mismatch between the spring client and the server
```

Is there a way to tell spring and guard to restart automatically upon such changes?

I'm doing something similar with my development server using the [rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) gem:

```
rerun --pattern '{Gemfile.lock,config/application.rb,config/environment.rb,config/environments/development.rb,config/initializers/*.rb,lib/**/*.rb,config/database.yml,config/boot.rb}' --no-growl --signal INT --background --clear -- rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

This makes that whenever one of the following files changes, the server restarts:

- Gemfile.lock
- config/application.rb
- config/environment.rb
- config/environments/development.rb
- config/initializers/*.rb,lib/**/*.rb
- config/database.yml
- config/boot.rb

I could do something similar using guard for sure, but I hope there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is in the documentation for Spring I believe but here are the relevant parts in our application. I don't think you need to restart guard though do you? Its just watching for changes and running things for you.

config/spring.rb

`Spring.watch "config/database.yml"
Spring.watch "Gemfile.lock"`

As for reloading Guard itself I'm not sure you'll need it but this answer will do it for you [Reloading Guardfile on changes to files other than the Guardfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511991/reloading-guardfile-on-changes-to-files-other-than-the-guardfile)